# Kivy - change FileChooser defaul location

Tags: android, python, kivy, python-3.5

Right now the file chooser opens the very root as the default location but i want it to skip that and open as default the internal storage (sdcard) and the user can go down from there.

this is a snipped of my code so far
The class:

```
class LoadDialog(FloatLayout):
    load = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)
```

The definition in the kv file

```
<LoadDialog>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancel()

            Button:
                text: "Load"
                on_release: root.load(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)
```

The actual load code:

```
def show_load(self):
        content = LoadDialog(load=self.load, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Load file", content=content,
                            size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

def load(self, path, filename):
        wimg = os.path.join(path, filename[0])
        self.image_source = wimg
        self.dismiss_popup()
```

So basically the user should not have to go up 1 directory to get to the sdcard, should already be there. Worst case scenario is filtering all the other folders there except the ones that contain the word sdcard.

Comment: Paths to sd cards nowadays do not contain the word sdcard. And sd card is not internal storage.

Comment: well from what i saw, in android 4 at least the internal storage is sdcard which is a symblink. The location I need is basically the parent of the DCIM folder

Comment: That will be getExternalStorageDirectory() then.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the path attribute.

```
FileChooserListView:
    id: filechooser
    path: "/your/path"
```

To find a directory on your system with python, you can do something like this:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/"):
    for name in dirs:
        if name == "DCIM":
            print(root, name)
```

Just be aware that it might find two or more directories named DCIM, on your sdcard and internal storage.

Comment: Just as a general thing, i know on my HTC phone the DCIM folder is in the directory called sdcard. Is there a way to ALWAYS find the DCIM folder? or at least the internal storage?

Comment: @Nick are you saying sdcard is a folder on internal storage?

Comment: yeah, sdcard is internal storage, i also have sdcard2 which is external from what i could figure out

Comment: How would we set it to the current working directory automatically though?

Comment: @PyWalker2797 path="."